# Exported image filename customization from devexpress ReportPrintTool

Tags: devexpress, xtrareport, devexpress-windows-ui

I am using Devexpress XtraReport suite in my application which works fine for dynamic reporting requirement except one customization as below:

User is given report preview using ReportPrintTool with dynamic data.
Now, when user tries to export print preview as Image file with 'ExportMode=Different Files' output file names are generated based on report name(i.e. reportName+pageIndex.png) which i need to define based on some dynamic value or say based on a column value provided to report as data source.

Can anybody please guide me how can I achieve this customization?

Answer (score 0):

*Reference from:* [XtraReport default file name in SaveDialog box](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q274773)

Try to set the XtraReport.ExportOptions.PrintPreview.DefaultFileName option ([PrintPreviewOptions.DefaultFileName Property](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraPrintingPrintPreviewOptions_DefaultFileNametopic)).

```
PrintControl.PrintingSystem.ExportOptions.PrintPreview.DefaultFileName = "column value that you provide"
```

To know that how to use it, Follow the below reference links:
[default name of report during saving](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q146333) - Here some file name standard related issue also descripbed
[How modify predefined file name on exporting report](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q239231)
[XtraReports - Custom filename when exporting via the reports toolbar](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q477399)

Comment: Yes exactly if I can do this way but in case when i want to use any single value from data source. Here, my report is generated single page for single record and so i want to set each page's filename value from its corresponding record value.

Comment: @binarymnl: Go though the reference links.. you will defiantly find solution as you asking to do.. i have just shown you reference code snippet, but reference links will provide much concise details as you want to implement.